Use checkboxes to add or remove lines from a d3.js multiline chart
I'm using d3 to create a multiline chart. I've added a checkbox to each legend entry that corresponds to a line with the idea that one can uncheck a box to remove the line, re-check a box to add it back.
As it stands now, I'm redrawing the chart every time a checkbox is selected. If if it's the first time the drawChart function runs, I make every checkbox selected.
If a checkbox is selected, the data is filtered and the drawChart function runs again, this time comparing the original data with the new data.
While it (sort of) works, the legend colors are changing, and I feel like this is incredibly cumbersome. Is there a better approach?


let timeW = 960,
  timeH = 450

let timeMargin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 300,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 60
  },
  timeWidth = timeW - timeMargin.left - timeMargin.right,
  timeHeight = timeH - timeMargin.top - timeMargin.bottom;

var x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, timeWidth]),
  y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([timeHeight, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x2),
  yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y2);

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x2(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y2(d.value);
  });

const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sprucegoose1/sample-data/main/age.csv").then(function(data) {
  var long_data = [];
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    row.date = parseDate(row.Date)
    let tableKeys = data.columns.slice(1);
    Object.keys(row).forEach(function(colname) {
      if (colname !== "date" && colname !== "Date") {
        long_data.push({
          "date": row["date"],
          "value": +row[colname],
          "bucket": colname
        });
      }
    });
  });

  data.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date)

  let dataNest = d3.group(long_data, d => d.bucket)
  let tableKeys = data.columns.slice(1);

  drawChart(long_data, dataNest, tableKeys, "init")
})

function drawChart(data, dataNest, tableKeys, which) {
  d3.select("#timeseries").remove()

  let timeseries = d3.select("#chart").append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'timeseries')
    .attr("width", timeWidth + timeMargin.left + timeMargin.right)
    .attr("height", timeHeight + timeMargin.top + timeMargin.bottom)

  var graph = timeseries.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + timeMargin.left + ',' + timeMargin.top + ')');

  var focus = timeseries.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + timeMargin.left + "," + timeMargin.top + ")");

  x2.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  y2.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })]);

  const seriesColors = ['#ff3300', 'royalblue', 'green', 'turquoise', 'navy']

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(seriesColors);

  focus
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(dataNest)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr('class', 'groups')
    .attr("d", d => {
      d.line = this;
      return line(d[1]);
    })
    .style("stroke", d => color(d[0]))
    .style("stroke-width", 1)
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

  focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + timeHeight + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(yAxis);

  // add a legend
  if (which == "init") {
    var legend = timeseries.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend')
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (timeW - timeMargin.right + 10) + "," + timeMargin.top + ")")

    var legendGroups = legend
      .selectAll(".legendGroup")
      .data(tableKeys, d => d)

    var enterGroups = legendGroups
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", d => "legendGroup " + d.replaceAll(" ", "_"))

    legendGroups
      .exit()
      .remove();

    enterGroups.append("text")
      .attr('class', 'legend-text')
      .text(d => d)
      .attr("x", 45)
      .attr("y", (d, i) => 10 + i * 20);

    enterGroups
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .attr("fill", d => color(d))
      .attr("x", 30)
      .attr("y", (d, i) => i * 20)
      .attr("class", d => d + ' legend-rect')

    enterGroups
      .append("foreignObject")
      .attr("x", 15)
      .attr("y", (d, i) => i * 20)
      .attr("width", 12)
      .attr("height", 13)
      .attr("id", (d, i) => 'a' + i)
      .append("xhtml:div")
      .html("<input type='checkbox' checked class='check'>")
      .attr('class', 'checkcontainer')
  }
  // legend items for all data, but update checkboxes checked
  else if (which == "checkBoxes") {
    let oldKeys = ['18-25', '26-40', '41-55', '56+', '<18']

    var legend = timeseries.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend')
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (timeW - timeMargin.right + 10) + "," + timeMargin.top + ")")

    var legendGroups = legend
      .selectAll(".legendGroup")
      .data(oldKeys, d => d)

    var enterGroups = legendGroups
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", d => "legendGroup " + d.replaceAll(" ", "_"))

    legendGroups
      .exit()
      .remove();

    enterGroups.append("text")
      .attr('class', 'legend-text')
      .text(d => d)
      .attr("x", 45)
      .attr("y", (d, i) => 10 + i * 20);

    enterGroups
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .attr("fill", d => color(d))
      .attr("x", 30)
      .attr("y", (d, i) => i * 20)
      .attr("class", d => d + ' legend-rect')

    enterGroups
      .append("foreignObject")
      .attr("x", 15)
      .attr("y", (d, i) => i * 20)
      .attr("width", 12)
      .attr("height", 13)
      .attr("id", (d, i) => 'a' + i)
      .append("xhtml:div")
      .html(function(d) {
        if (tableKeys.indexOf(d) >= 0) {
          return "<input type='checkbox' checked class='check'>"
        } else {
          return "<input type='checkbox' class='check'>"
        }
      })
      .attr('class', 'checkcontainer')
  }

  d3.selectAll('.check').on('click', function(d) {
    let isChecked = this.checked

    let parentEnterGroup = d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode)
    let parentGroupClass = parentEnterGroup._groups[0]
    let parentGroupString = parentGroupClass[0].className.baseVal.split(" ")[1]

    if (isChecked !== true) {
      let newData = data.filter(d => d.bucket !== parentGroupString.replaceAll("_", " "))

      let newDataNest = d3.group(newData, d => d.bucket)
      let newTableKeysa = Array.from(newDataNest.keys())

      drawChart(newData, newDataNest, newTableKeysa, "checkBoxes")
    } else {
      console.log('add it back')
    }
  })

};
#chart {
  height: 450px;
  width: 760px;
}

.check {
  width: 11px;
  height: 12px;
  filter: grayscale(1);
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -1px !important;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>




Personally I dislike using check boxes within the SVG as foreign objects. While you can keep them, I'm just going to use SVG rectangles and will toggle their fill when clicked, using a stroke to keep their boundaries visible. Though the approach in this answer works with checkboxes as well.
We need some method to track whether a box is clicked, for ease, I just added a property to the check boxes' data, d.clicked. When a box is clicked, we:

toggle the datum's clicked value between false/true
either remove or re-add its fill based on d.clicked
use css to hide/show the associated graph line

The below shows this with a placeholder for the third point:


let data = ["one","two","three"];
let colors = ["crimson","steelblue","forestgreen"]

let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")

let clickedItems = [];

let buttons = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  // use an object as the datum to allow easier modification later:
  .datum(function(d) { return {name: d, clicked: false}})
  .attr("transform", (d,i)=>"translate("+[5,i*20+10]+")");
  
buttons.append("text")
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("x", 16)
  .text(d=>d.name)
  
buttons.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 12)
  .attr("height",12)
  .attr("fill", (d,i)=>colors[i])
  .attr("stroke", (d,i)=>colors[i])
  .style("cursor", "pointer")
  .attr("class", "legend-rect")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .on("click", function(event,d) {
      // Get the index of the node to help select corresponding data:
      // Unused here as I don't have a corresponding graph
      //let i = d3.selectAll(".legend-rect").nodes().indexOf(this);
      
      // record whether a box is clicked or not:
      d.clicked = !d.clicked;
      
      // toggle the rectangle's fill
      d3.select(this).attr("fill", d.clicked ? "transparent" : colors[i]);
      
      // Hide/show the data logic:
      // Unused here as I don't have a corresponding graph
      // d3.selectAll("#identifier"+i).style("display", d.clicked ? "none" : "");
        
      // If we want to track if all boxes are unchecked:
      // Track which boxes are checked:
      d.clicked ? clickedItems.push(d.name) : clickedItems.splice(clickedItems.indexOf(d.name),1);  
       
      // If all are empty:
      if(clickedItems.length == data.length) {
           d3.selectAll(".legend-rect")
              .attr("fill", (d,i) => colors[i])
              .each(d=>d.clicked  = false);
          // clear clicked items array:
          clickedItems = [];
          // Logic for redrawing all data:
            // d3.selectAll(".identifier")
            //  .style("display", "");
      }      
  })
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>



In addition to the above points, I've also added a quick check using an array (clickedItems) to see if all boxes are unchecked, which will result in all checkboxes being refilled and all the data shown (again, just a placeholder for this as I don't have an actual mocked up graph). One additional feature that could easily be added is a double click to remove all other lines.
I've used this approach with your code. I've also added some logic to update the scales of the graph based on what data is shown. There are some optimizations that can be made.
By using CSS to hide/show the data, the data will always retain the same order and index thus keeping the same color.


let timeW = 960,
  timeH = 450

let timeMargin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 300,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 60
  },
  timeWidth = timeW - timeMargin.left - timeMargin.right,
  timeHeight = timeH - timeMargin.top - timeMargin.bottom;

var x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, timeWidth]),
  y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([timeHeight, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x2),
  yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y2);

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x2(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y2(d.value);
  });

const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sprucegoose1/sample-data/main/age.csv").then(function(data) {
  var long_data = [];
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    row.date = parseDate(row.Date)
    let tableKeys = data.columns.slice(1);
    Object.keys(row).forEach(function(colname) {
      if (colname !== "date" && colname !== "Date") {
        long_data.push({
          "date": row["date"],
          "value": +row[colname],
          "bucket": colname
        });
      }
    });
  });

  data.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date)

  let dataNest = d3.group(long_data, d => d.bucket)
  let tableKeys = data.columns.slice(1);

  drawChart(long_data, dataNest, tableKeys, "init")
})

function drawChart(data, dataNest, tableKeys, which) {

  d3.select("#timeseries").remove()

  let timeseries = d3.select("#chart").append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'timeseries')
    .attr("width", timeWidth + timeMargin.left + timeMargin.right)
    .attr("height", timeHeight + timeMargin.top + timeMargin.bottom)

  var graph = timeseries.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + timeMargin.left + ',' + timeMargin.top + ')');

  var focus = timeseries.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + timeMargin.left + "," + timeMargin.top + ")");

  x2.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  y2.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })]);

  const seriesColors = ['#ff3300', 'royalblue', 'green', 'turquoise', 'navy']

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(seriesColors);

  focus
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(dataNest)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr('class', function(d,i) { return 'groups group'+i; })
    .attr("d", d => {
      d.line = this;
      return line(d[1]);
    })
    .style("stroke", d => color(d[0]))
    .style("stroke-width", 1)
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

  var gXAxis = focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + timeHeight + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  var gYAxis = focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(yAxis);

 
 var clickedItems = [];
 
 var legend = timeseries.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend')
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (timeW - timeMargin.right + 10) + "," + timeMargin.top + ")")

  var legendGroups = legend
      .selectAll(".legendGroup")
      .data(tableKeys, d => d)
      .enter()
       .datum((d)=> d={clicked: false, name: d} )
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", (d,i)=>"translate("+[0,i*20]+")");
      
    legendGroups.append("text")
      .attr('class', 'legend-text')
      .text(d => d.name)
      .attr("x", 45)
      .attr("y", 10);
 

    legendGroups.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .attr("fill", d => color(d))
      .attr("stroke", d=>color(d))
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .style("cursor","pointer")
      .attr("x", 30)
      .attr("class", d => ' legend-rect')
      .on("click", function(event,d) {
            // record whether it is clicked or not:
            d.clicked = !d.clicked;
            // toggle the rectangle's fill
            d3.select(this).attr("fill", d.clicked ? "transparent" : d=>color(d.name));
            // hide/show the associated line
            let i = d3.selectAll(".legend-rect").nodes().indexOf(this);
            d3.selectAll(".group"+i).style("display", d.clicked ? "none" : "");
            
            // Logic for all empty:
            // keep track of unchecked boxes (also used in rescaling below):
            d.clicked ? clickedItems.push(d.name) : clickedItems.splice(clickedItems.indexOf(d.name),1);           
            
            // If all are empty:
            if(clickedItems.length == tableKeys.length) {
              d3.selectAll(".legend-rect")
                .attr("fill", d => color(d.name))
                .each(d=>d.clicked  = false);
              d3.selectAll(".groups")
                .style("display", "");
              clickedItems = [];
            }            
          
            // For re-scaling:
            // filter scale values       
            x2.domain(d3.extent(data.filter(d=>clickedItems.indexOf(d.bucket) == -1), function(d) {
              return d.date;
            }));
            y2.domain([0, d3.max(data.filter(d=>clickedItems.indexOf(d.bucket) == -1), function(dd) {
                return dd.value;
            })]);
           
            gYAxis.call(yAxis)
            gXAxis.call(xAxis)
            
            focus.selectAll("path.groups")
              .transition() // May want to use clip area for the line here.
              .attr("d", d => {
                return line(d[1]);
             })
            
            
            
      })
      
     

  
 
  

};
#chart {
  height: 450px;
  width: 760px;
}

.check {
  width: 11px;
  height: 12px;
  filter: grayscale(1);
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -1px !important;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>




thank you very much for the thorough explanation!
